# How to access button names in the storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

> How do I access this name in code, not the title:

[image]

I find this could be useful as an id of any objects on the storyboard.

Comment: hi you have create IBOutlate for that button and use this code to acccess title

Comment: NSString *strTagValue =_btnTitle.titleLabel.text;

Comment: i did not know about swift but this work in objective c and i am using this way

Comment: @Birendra get it!

Comment: Is this the name of its IBOutlet in the ViewController?

Comment: @AhmadF I haven't connected an outlet yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in this case, the name that appears in the storyboard is just your outlet name. But in other cases, that name can be lots of things, like the text on your button. Since it can be so many values I doubt there is a way to get it except looking at the source code of Xcode itself. But I think Xcode is not open source.

If you want an id for your view, use `tag`. Every view has a `tag` property. You can set it to some integer and use the `viewWithTag` method to get the view back!

If you insist on using strings as ids, create a dictionary that maps your string id to the `tag`

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are new to iOS,

When you drag a button on to view it will have a default title of "Button" when you check its name it will be "Button", now if you select the button and change its title to "ABCD" and if you see the view hierarchy it will show the button as "ABCD".

Finally if you drag an IBOutlet from button to your VC and name the IBOutlet as "ABCD1234" now its name in view hierarchy is shown as "ABCD1234"

Summary is it is showing the same button, as long as there is no IBOutlet to it or its IBOutlet is named something other than its title its name will be shown as title, when you rename its IBOutlet to different from title its name is shown as the name of IBOutlet.

The concept of ID and then using `findViewById("ID string")` is not in iOS, if you want to access the view/button you create a IBOutlet to it :)

Comment: I bet many people with less than 2 years of experience don't know this, no tutorial or book ever taught this :)

Comment: @bright-future : Am sorry If i my words " Looks like you are new to iOS," did hurt you, It is usually android developers trying to make their way into iOS development make a mistake of declaring id and finding it using findViewById which is pretty common in android :) Hence said that :) Hope you find ur answer :)

Comment: In my use case, accessing the button by its outlet creates some extra work, I think @Sweeper's solution suits me better.

Comment: nah it didn't , I have no experience in Android, just feel this is the most intuitive way of looking at it, if it has a name in storyboard, why can't I get that name?

Comment: @bright-future : That depends on your coding practice and your requirements buddy :) Am glad you solved ur confusion :) Go ahead and accept the answer :)

Comment: @bright-future : As sweeper already pointed out rather than accessing the view by name iOS has a property of tag, where you can assign a unique value to tag of each view and then get it by calling viewWithTag unfortunately there is no api as viewWithName :) Though I should tell you finding viewByTag involves a little overhead as in runtime iOS has to pass through all the subviews in ViewController/parent view to find the one that matches the tag :)

Comment: Though this isn't a heavy operation, using it on a view with large number of sub views stacked up can incur a little over head :) Creating a IBOutlet is a little overhead when it comes to work but you will get the access to specific view in one shot no parsing needed :)

Comment: I see, but what I wanna do is setting a matching image for the button, if I find the image by switching through all possible outlets or by a dictionary, it won't be as convenient as UIImage(named: "tagName") I guess. Thanks for letting me know this though

Comment: As I already said using the tag or IBOulets completely depends on your requirement :) Now rather than naming the image as tag of the view I can rename it to match the name of the IBoutlet as well and can use the same method rather than passing the tag I can now pass the IBOutlet name as well :) It completely depends on ur requirement :)

Comment: yeah you are right, I just found out the tag can only be Int, naming my images that way is not a good idea, so I'll use dictionaries instead